# present perfect continous or past perfect continuous in this case?

Tags: past-tense

> Wild Zeros started in Bordeaux in late 2007 - first gig in December of that year. Just a bunch of friends (ex or current members of Magnetix, Pneumonias, Mean Things, Skeptics, Wylde Tryfles…) who wanted to play Garage Punk music together and pay a tribute to their long time favourites such as The Troggs, DMZ, Penetrators and way more. **They’ve been** touring all over France playing with bands such as The Zeros, Sonic Chicken 4 or Jerry Spider Gang and releasing a 7’’ and a 10’’ on Frantic City Records as well as a split 7’’ with The Baxx Sisi’s from New York on Brooklyn-based Chickpea Records before taking a long break.
>
> Five or so years later the same Chickpea Records is putting out an ‘Early Recordings’ tape as well as organising a release party in Brooklyn and the band is hitting the road again, still with the three original members, celebrating their 10 years with a new recording session done with none other than Trash Master Lo’Spider in Toulouse

I think it should be had not have here, because they have not toured for a long time and have not planned to do it again

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the chronology. If the "ex or current members..."  were touring when the Wild Zeros were formed (as in, the members met while they were on tour with their former groups and came together to form a new group, the Wild Zeros), then I'd use past perfect continuous. And I'd perhaps augment it with a phrase to make the series of events more clear.

> The members had been touring all over France with their original groups [...]. This is when they came together to form the Wild Zeros.

But, it sounds like you are recounting the history of the group. If this is the case, then paste tense is fine:

> The Wild Zeros were formed in Bordeaux in late 2007. They **toured** all over France, playing with bands such as The Zeros, Sonic Chicken 4, and Jerry Spider Gang and **released** a 7" and a 10" with Frantic City Records.

You also have a lot of sentence fragments and run-ons. Here are some things I would tweak:

> **The** Wild Zeros started in Bordeaux in late 2007. **Their** first gig **was** in December of that year.

The second part was a sentence fragment. Add a verb to make it a sentence. You also may want to use "formed" instead of "started." The former has more of a connotation with bands.

> Just a bunch of friends (ex or current members of Magnetix, Pneumonias, Mean Things, Skeptics, Wylde Tryfles…) who wanted to play Garage Punk music together and pay a tribute to their long time favourites such as The Troggs, DMZ, Penetrators and way more.

This is a pretty long sentence. I'd break it up:

> **They were** just a bunch of friends who wanted to play **garage punk** music together and pay **<strike>a</strike>** tribute to their long-time favorites such as The Troggs, DMZ, **the** Penetrators, and **many** more. **They were former or current members of other groups such as** Magnetix, Pneumonias, Mean Things, Skeptics, and Wylde Tryfles.

I wouldn't capitalize genres in sentence context. You "pay tribute" not "pay a tribute."

The next sentence is also rather long. I'd break it up:

> **As a group, they toured** all over France, playing wit bands such as The Zeros, Sonic Chicken 4, **and** the Jerry Spider Gang. **They also produced** a 7" and 10" **for** Frantic City Records as well as a split 7" with The Baxx Sisi's **for the** Brooklyn-based Chickpea Records before taking a long break.

Comment: nice answer, may be the author used present perfect continuous because all these groups Magnetix, Pneumonias, Mean Things, Skeptics, and Wylde Tryfles are still alive and touring but "they" represent the wild zeros so he made a mistake